# Get rows value as column on basis of group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
select * 
from tmp_vendor_style_no_20210104
order by vendor_style_no, serial_count desc
```

which returns an output like this:

[image]

but I want the result to look like this instead:

[image]

Rows are not fixed it can be 1,2 or many more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of rows, or unknown? For the latter you will need dynamic SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score -2):

I thing the best way to accomplish that is using [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) function in SQL. You have to identify the column of preference to set the record values.